# Does the "tools" tag need to be revised?

Tags: discussion, tags, migrate

I posted [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/82447/revisions) and the community has exiled it from ux.stackexchange. I was doubtful if ux.stackexchange was the right place for the question, but when I discovered the [tools](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag, I was reassured. Here's the description of the tools tag:

> Hardware or Software tools used by UX professionals to do their work.
>   Also more generally software used by users to shape or modify
>   something they are creating.

My question seemed strongly aligned with the above description, yet it was exiled.

Can we either 1) update the tag's description to more truly reflect the intention, or 2) bring back my question into ux.stackexchange?

Answer (score 1):

I've rolled back the previous excerpt that states:

> PLEASE THINK CAREFULLY IF YOU WANT TO USE THIS TAG! REQUESTS FOR TOOL RECOMMENDATIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC FOR STACK EXCHANGE SITES.  Hardware or Software tools used by UX professionals to do their work.  Also more generally software used by users to shape or modify something they are creating.

Thank you for letting us know that there where an issue with the tools excerpt.

The tag info is unchanged and says:

[image]